# How can I tell if SP1 has been installed on Team Foundation Server 2008?

Tags: tfs

How can I tell if SP1 has been installed for team foundation server 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the version of the file: %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll

- RTM - 9.0.21022.8
- SP1 - 9.0.30729.1

Higher versions include the GDR stuff.

Comment: Great.  Why they don't have any UI for team foundation server or atleast in windows->programs menu?  

And another thing I have noticed that date modified has been changed.